# Patching a binary without recompiling in VS2005

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005

I've got a problem, I'm probably in way over my head and was hoping that someone could help me out. My C++ skills are rather lacking, but I'm willing to learn.

I've got a Visual Studio 2005 C++ project here that generates an DLL for software we use. The problem is, my code is slightly newer than what the clients are using, and updating the clients is out of the question at this point in time.

I need to make some changes (mainly commenting out some functions and calls, changing some values, that's about it). Normally I would make the changes in the code and compile, but that gives me a binary that is incompatible with the clients (because they are outdated)

I have the *mostly* compatible code that generates the binary, and the binary itself. Surely there must be some way to patch the existing DLL with my changes, without actually compiling the project? I've never done any binary patching.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you looked into [Patchwiz](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370590(v=vs.85).aspx)? And did you originally compile with [`/hotpatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173507(VS.80).aspx)?

Comment: Thanks! No /hotpatch, as far as I can tell. How does patchwiz help me? It seems to be intended for mass-patching between two known states

Answer (score 0):

DLL's are actually designed to solve the problem that you describe, i.e. how do I fix a product in client's hand without recompiling the whole project? DLL founds a binary boundary that you can simply swap out.

*Unfortunately I think the best way is to recompile the DLLs.* Hopefully you hear me out below though. :)

Even though your code is newer than client's code, the interface you need to maintain is defined in the .def file. Therefore, as long as you are NOT breaking the original interface contract of the functions defined in the .def file, your code base can be totally different from the client's and that wouldn't matter.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d91k01sh(v=vs.80).aspx

In fact, you can add more functions to the .def file, as long as the original order of the older functions (and their signatures) doesn't change, you won't break your client's app. This is how Windows ships updated DLLs to their (quite large number of) clients.

Comment: Thanks! Wouldn't I need the .def file of the current version? All I have is the binary itself. :( Furthermore, there are have been changes between my code and the current version that affect the way the software communicates. I doubt very much I can make that compatible. Hacking the binary is probably the only option here...

Comment: Yes, you will need a .def file. Sorry, I'm not sure how the binary hacking can be done, other than reverse engineering the code by reading the assembly, modify the binary's assembly code. Do you have the symbol for the current binary in your client's hand? Depending on the scope of the change, you might find it hard to verify the hack doesn't negatively impact the intact of the rest of the software. And note that compilers often optimize the binary and you might find it hard to debug the software even with symbols.

Comment: Also, I'm a little bit confused, since your original question mentioned that you have a Visual Studio project so I assumed that you have the source code and hence the .def file, but your comment indicates that you have only the binary. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: No, you are correct. I have the VS project and sources, but only the new version of it. There are no .def files in it, though. Neither do I have debugging symbols for the clients' binaries. I'm in way over my head, aren't I? :) But thank you for sticking with me so far!

Comment: The scope of my changes is fairly small. Just changing some values and disabling some functions/calls. I think if I could read and edit the assembly like you proposed, it might be doable. But I don't see how I could do that without at least symbols. I'd be more or less stumbling around in the dark. Unless I can find some familiar strings, I suppose...

Comment: Removing a couple function, depending on where they are defined, could potentially change the v-table if it's defined in a interface, or the address of the function that they are defined. Not only do you have to remove the functions, you also have to change all the callers to the functions, which do not always simply put the address of the function in their jump operator. The address could be calculated by some base address with registers. It probably isn't as small a change as you imagine.

Comment: I would suggest you reevaluate your business constraints to see if you can find more help. For example, you can try to find the source control system (if one exist) and see the history of the project.